# Read SMS in Ionic 3 for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, typescript, ionic3, sms

We have an Ionic app in which we need to read a SMS with a validation code that the user will receive when registering into the app.

We are using [this](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) plugin which works perfectly in **Android**. But does not work on **IOS** it seems like.
I've also seen [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/) Native plugin but it does not support reading sms I don't think.

**This is how we read the sms:**

```
...
declare let SMS: any;

readListSMS() {
  let filter = {
    box: 'inbox',            // 'inbox' (default), 'sent', 'draft'
    address: '<phone-number>',
    indexFrom: 0,            // start from index 0
    maxCount: 1,             // count of SMS to return each time
    read: 0
  };
  if (SMS) {
    SMS.listSMS(filter,
      (smss) => {
        // Here we have access to those sms
      },
      error => {
        alert('error list sms: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
}
...
```

Problem is when building the app for ios it wont read the sms, well actually it doesn't even enter the callback.

From what I have read it does not feel possible, also there is not much info about this subject on the internets!

**My questions are:**

- Is it something to do with ios permissions? If so, any help on this would be nice!
- Anybody know of a way of accomplishing this for IOS?

Comment: There is no way to access user messages in iOS. There has never been, and probably never will be. iOS 12 will suggest security codes from messages ( https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/04/safari-security-code-auto-fill/ ) but I haven’t found any info if this will work in 3rd party apps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, just what I thought!

Comment: Let the user do it manually since Apple doesn't have APIs to read SMS inbox

Comment: Okey thanks, I thinks its solved...